# Tooltip is not refreshing in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am retrieving tooltip from tag property as below and tag property has refreshed/correct tool tip but while creating new tool tip i am not getting refreshed one. On mouse hover i am calling this create tool tip method. Can some one explain this why i am not getting the refreshed tooltip in my control ?

```
private void CreateToolTip(Border border, RealisticControlBase control)
            {
                border.SetValue(ToolTipService.IsEnabledProperty, false);     
                if (control != null)
                {
                    FrameworkElement tooltip = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(border) as FrameworkElement;
                    control.InvalidateArrange();
                    tooltip.InvalidateArrange();
                    if ((control.Tag as string) != null)
                    {
                        string templatename = control.Tag.ToString();
                        object abc=Application.Current.FindResource(templatename);
                        if ((Application.Current.FindResource(templatename) as DataTemplate) != null)
                        {
                            (tooltip as ToolTip).ContentTemplate = Application.Current.FindResource(templatename) as DataTemplate;
                            tooltip.DataContext = control.DataContext;
                            border.SetValue(ToolTipService.IsEnabledProperty, true);
                            (tooltip as ToolTip).Content = control.DataContext;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct question and answers is why not bind your control's tooltip to the tag property and let wpf worry about the refresh logic.

Comment: It works for some controls but when i changed the template using some property then while creating tool tip is not refreshed